# PRESTASHOP 1.7 | Obtener el valor de un atributo de un producto en TPL

Tags: prestashop1.7

Estoy trabajando con PRESTASHOP 1.7, he creado varios atributos para los productos, el caso es que, si el producto que se está viendo tiene un atributo en concreto, quiero mostrar un código HTML especifico, y necesito que sea en TPL.

Mi problema es, que no sé como acceder a los atributos de un producto, necesito una condición para poder comprobar, que si el valor de un atributo es tal se muestre el código HTML de dentro de la condición.

He visto por internet que utilizando algo parecido a esto: '$product.id_product_attribute == 0 or >0'

Pero no creo que me sirva, ese código creo que solamente indica si el producto tiene atributos o no, yo necesito, saber si un producto tiene un atributo concreto y saber su valor.

Soy nuevo con esto de PRESTASHOP y los TPLs por lo que no se muy bien como funciona todo esto realmente.

Esto es lo poco que tengo, en el if es donde tendría que ir la condición para comprobar si el producto tiene dicho atributo o no, y de ser así, comprobar su valor.

```
{if $product.}
    <div class="">
    </div>
{/if}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Hola @icortazar Lo has logrado? te ha servido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes probar esto:

```
{if $product.attributes}
    ....
{/if}
```

o también

```
{if !empty($product.attributes)}
     ....
{/if}
```

Dentro del if puedes hacer `{$product.attributes|var_dump}`  y ver las variables y los datos que te puede interesar para usarlo.